# Application crashing on creating a new object instance of ComponentDefinition Blackberry 10 Native

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I am creating a new object instance of a ComponentDefinition using createObject() and then adding it to a container. My application crashes when it reaches the said line of code in QML.

Here is my code:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import Data.UpdateReservationView 1.0    //a custom C++ qmlRegisterType

Page {
   property alias resDetails: updateRes.resDetails

   attachedObjects: [
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: enhLabel
            Label {
                textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.PointValue
                textStyle.fontSizeValue: 5.5
                textStyle.color: Color.Black
            }    
        },

        UpdateReservationView {
            id: updateRes 
        }
   ]

   onResDetailsChanged: {
     // some code

     var newLabel = enhLabel.createObject();  //the app crashes upon reaching this line
     newLabel.text = resDetails[i]["roomName"];
     labelsContainer.add(newLabel);
   }

   ScrollView {
            topMargin: 30.0
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            Container{
                leftPadding: 20.0
                rightPadding: leftPadding
                bottomPadding: 50.0
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                Container { 
                   id: labelsContainer
                   horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Left
                   verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                }
            }
   } //ScrollView ends
} //Page ends
```

I have tried using `.load()` instead of `.createObject()` but get the same result as the **ComponentDefinition (enhLabel)** is being instantiated elswhere in the code too, and according to my understanding .load() simply loads the control once whereas I require a new instance of it to be created multiple times dynamically.

The queer thing is that the code was running perfectly the day before and I've made no changes in this particular QML file. 
What could be the reason for the application to crash. I am sure that it crashes upon reaching the `var newLabel = enhLabel.createObject()` line by using the old school console.debug() method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what has changed on your side but according to the code sample on the [BB developer site](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__qmlcomponentdefinition.html) from what I can see your code looks ok:

```
Container {
    Button {
        text: "Click to create bordered text"
        onClicked: {
             // Creates borderedTextComponent control and appends it
             // to the container
             var createdControl = borderedTextComponent.createObject();
             container.add(createdControl);
             createdControl.textString = "Hello Component";
             createdControl.padding = 30;
             createdControl.textColor = Color.DarkGray;
        }
    } 
    Container {
        id: container
    }
    attachedObjects: [
         ComponentDefinition {
             id: borderedTextComponent

             Container {
                 property variant borderColor: Color.Red
                 property variant fillColor: Color.White
                 property variant textColor: Color.Black
                 property string textString
                 property real padding: 10;

                 background: borderColor

                 leftPadding: padding
                 rightPadding: padding
                 topPadding: padding
                 bottomPadding: padding

                 Container {
                     background: fillColor
                     Label { 
                         text: textString
                         textStyle.color: textColor
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     ]
}
```

Maybe try this sample to see whether you've got an environmental problem, this one worked for me inside a standard empty Cascades project and paste the code inside the Page{}.

Unfortunately too many things from your code are missing to reproduce the crash on my end.